# Download interrupted on Terminal - cannot reinstall

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, sudo, packages

I was downloading the `icedtea-7-plugin` package for Ubuntu on the Terminal. I used the `sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin` just like any other person would and I turned back to what I was doing, for I knew it was going to take some time for my connection to download the whole thing.

But I later had some urgent work to do so I put my laptop on sleep mode. I came back and saw how the download was interrupted. So I used `sudo apt-get install --reinstall icedtea-7-plugin` and it was giving me this error:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
enter preformatted text here
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process
using it
```

I went to the directory `/var/lib/dpkg` and tried to remove all the files by `rm -f` or even `sudo apt-get remove icedtea-7-plugin` but it gives me exactly the same error in both the cases.

What is the solution for this problem?

Comment: @terdon It's a transliteration of my name: Parth Kohli

Comment: rm: cannot remove ‘lock’: Permission denied

Comment: I have not removed dpkg. I only tried to, but it gave me the same error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9009/discussion-between---and-terdon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, the lock file is just there to stop you from running multiple `dpkg` processes at once. The first thing you should try is

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

If that doesn't work, have a look at which processes are actually using `apt` or `dpkg`:

```
ps aux | grep 'apt\|dpkg'
```

Your hanged process should be one of those, you can kill it with

```
kill PID
```

where PID is its process ID number, the second field of the above `ps` output.

However, the easiest way to fix this would be to simply log out and log back in, or at worst, to reboot.

Comment: Let me try to reboot. lock is removed, but it now asks me to configure, which again is giving me an error. BRB!

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to understand the output of the second command.